# "Long" read only text on selection screen

Tags: text, abap, sap-selection-screens

I need to display some information for the user on my selection screen.

Best way would be directly on the screen, so no pop-ups. I tried to use parameters with default value and read only but the length is limited.

Is there a way to get an information text on the selection screen which is a bit longer?

Comment: Try a text edit control. Class `CL_GUI_TEXTEDIT` or check the sample reports `SAPTEXTEDIT_DEMO_1` etc.

Comment: How long is "a bit longer"?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe `SELECTION-SCREEN COMMENT` would be of any use?

Here is an example.

```
REPORT zzz.

SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF BLOCK BLCK1 WITH FRAME TITLE TEXT-001.
PARAMETERS: p_p1 TYPE i.
SELECTION-SCREEN COMMENT /10(79) value.
SELECTION-SCREEN COMMENT /1(79) value1.
SELECTION-SCREEN COMMENT /1(79) value2.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF BLOCK BLCK1.

INITIALIZATION.
  value = `This is`.
  value1 = `a comment to the user`.
  value2 = `This comment line is much much much much much much much longer than 79 characters.`.
```

There is a limit of 79 characters per line though.

[image: Selection screen]